# The connection to Mysql not closing

Tags: php, mysql, apache

One of my site using Apache + PHP + Mysql did not releasing connections. The connection number kept growing. And the connection status is sleep.

```
| 138 | root | localhost       | NULL  | Sleep   |  183 |       | NULL             |
| 140 | root | localhost:50488 | A | Sleep   |  256 |       | NULL             |
| 142 | root | localhost:50512 | A | Sleep   |  253 |       | NULL             |
| 151 | root | localhost:50668 | A | Sleep   |  222 |       | NULL             |
| 152 | root | localhost:50684 | A | Sleep   |  221 |       | NULL             |
| 155 | root | localhost:50714 | A | Sleep   |  214 |       | NULL             |
| 157 | root | localhost:50751 | A | Sleep   |  207 |       | NULL             |
```

Check which connected to mysql using port 50488:

```
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mysqld  17147  mysql   15u  IPv4 150696739      0t0  TCP localhost:mysql->localhost:50488 (ESTABLISHED)
httpd   17487 apache   18u  IPv4 150696738      0t0  TCP localhost:50488->localhost:mysql (ESTABLISHED)
```

It is ridiculous since PHP closing the connection when script end automatically.

Any reason may cause this problem?

Comment: it might be some of your pages is running ridiculously slow, that's mean the connection established and the top of the page, subsequently the page is STILL waiting for other resource to response, mysql connection is then still active (this explain why the connection is in sleep status)

Comment: @ajreal I can confirm the page is end successfully. and the status of connection is sleeping

Answer (score 3):

Are you using persistent connections? Don't use it.

More info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php

And, from my own experience, once we had the very same problem, and the solution was to change persistent connections to normal connections. I don't remember the details. This may be your case, or not.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is caused by

1. @ignore_user_abort(TRUE); kept the script never die.
2. there is an error in the code, and the connection not closed.

Comment: This is not a very helpful answer.  Please explain "@ignore_user_abort(TRUE)".  What is this, where is this and what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

Add `mysql_close($connection);` at the end of query... If you have multiple query in one file, add it at the end of the file only, like this:

```
</body>
</html>
<?php
    mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

**WHERE `$connection` is the variable gived to the `mysql_connect()`*

It will close the connection.

Comment: In theory this will close the connection, but what if it doesn't?